# Quarkus renarde and Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus-oidc

Is there any way to use Keycloak as OIDC solution with Renarde? It is something that I would like to do for a company I am building different solutions for but couldn't find nothing in the documentation.